# SQL Server 2005 - how to compare field value, and return a count if different, for every occurance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count

```
DECLARE @CURRENTSCHOOL TABLE (STUDENT VARCHAR(8), COURSE VARCHAR(8), SCHOOL VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @CURRENTSCHOOL VALUES ('10000000','MCR1010','11')
INSERT INTO @CURRENTSCHOOL VALUES ('12000000','MCR6080','11')
INSERT INTO @CURRENTSCHOOL VALUES ('13000000','MCR6090','15')

DECLARE @OTHERSCHOOLS TABLE (STUDENT VARCHAR(8), COURSE VARCHAR(8), SCHOOL VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @OTHERSCHOOLS VALUES ('10000000','MCR1010','11')
INSERT INTO @OTHERSCHOOLS VALUES ('10000000','MCR1011','14')
INSERT INTO @OTHERSCHOOLS VALUES ('10000000','MCR1012','15')
INSERT INTO @OTHERSCHOOLS VALUES ('12000000','MCR6080','19')
INSERT INTO @OTHERSCHOOLS VALUES ('13000000','MCR6090','15')
```

For the above sample data. Two tables. Currentschool and Otherschools.

Currentschool is the current course that a student is on including the schoolcode,
and is the main table.

OtherSchools is potentially other courses that a student can go on, in differing schools.

I need to compare the currentschool table against the otherschools table matched using the student id number, and for every different schoolcode in otherschools, it needs to return a count.

eg:

```
Student:    OtherSchoolCount:
10000000    2        (because of 2 different school codes than than the current school)
12000000    1        (because of 1 different school code than than the current school)
13000000    blank    (because not a different school code)
```

Is this possible?

Many thanks

M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT cs.student, 
       COUNT(os.course) 
FROM   @CURRENTSCHOOL cs 
       LEFT JOIN @OTHERSCHOOLS os 
         ON cs.student = os.student 
            AND cs.school <> os.school 
GROUP  BY cs.student
```

outputs

```
STUDENT  
-------- -----------
10000000 2
12000000 1
13000000 0
```

If Null is really preferred over Zero then you can do this (or use the equivalent CTE)

```
SELECT student, 
       CASE 
         WHEN coursecount = 0 THEN NULL 
         ELSE coursecount 
       END coursecount 
FROM   (SELECT cs.student, 
               COUNT(os.course) coursecount 
        FROM   @CURRENTSCHOOL cs 
               LEFT JOIN @OTHERSCHOOLS os 
                 ON cs.student = os.student 
                    AND cs.school <> os.school 
        GROUP  BY cs.student) t
```

Which outputs

```
student  courseCount
-------- -----------
10000000 2
12000000 1
13000000 NULL
```

Update: NullIF could be put to use as alternative to the Case statement see [What applications are there for NULLIF()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6220956/119477)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. I'm giving the points to this one.

Answer (score 3):

```
select o.Student, count(*) as Count
from CURRENTSCHOOL c1 
inner join OTHERSCHOOLS o on c1.Student = o.Student --this join is to ensure student exists in both tables 
left outer join CURRENTSCHOOL c on o.Student = c.Student
    and o.School= c.School
where c.Student is null
group by o.Student
```

Comment: You're missing the `GROUP BY` the word `JOIN` next to `LEFT OUTER` and this results in 2 records `13000000` won't appear in the output

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `13000000` still won't appear in the results

Comment: @Conrad that is by design, the OP said *return a count if different* in the title; they later added sample output data that conflicts with this