# What applications are there for NULLIF()?

Tags: sql

I just had a trivial but genuine use for `NULLIF()`, for the first time in my career in SQL.  Is it a widely used tool I've just ignored, or a nearly-forgotten quirk of SQL?  It's present in all major database implementations.

If anyone needs a refresher, `NULLIF(A, B)` returns the first value, unless it's equal to the second in which case it returns `NULL`.  It is equivalent to this `CASE` statement:

```
CASE WHEN A <> B OR B IS NULL THEN A END
```

or, in C-style syntax:

```
A == B || A == null ? null : A
```

So far the only non-trivial example I've found is to exclude a specific value from an aggregate function:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(Comment, 'Downvoted'))
```

This has the limitation of only allowing one to skip a single value; a `CASE`, while more verbose, would let you use an expression.

For the record, the use I found was to suppress the value of a "most recent change" column if it was equal to the first change:

```
SELECT Record, FirstChange, NULLIF(LatestChange, FirstChange) AS LatestChange
```

This was useful only in that it reduced visual clutter for human consumers.

Comment: @N8: Sure.  "What applications are there for `NULLIF`?"  Does anyone actually use this function?

Comment: I used it yesterday [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213788/sql-where-clause-with-case-statement/6214522#6214522). The idea is a single expression using `NULLIF` and `COALESCE` is easier to read and maintain for a human than two expressions or a `CASE` statement. Compare how compact mine is compared to other answers :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask and read it closely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three years later, I found a material use for NULLIF: using `NULLIF(Field, '')` translates empty strings into NULL, for equivalence with Oracle's peculiar idea about what "NULL" represents.

Answer (score 8):

I rather think that

```
NULLIF(A, B)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
CASE WHEN A = B THEN NULL ELSE A END
```

But you are correct: it is mere syntactic sugar to aid the human reader.

Answer (score 6):

I often use it where I need to avoid the Division by Zero exception:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(Expression1 / NULLIF(Expression2, 0), 0) AS Result
FROM …
```

Answer (score 1):

`NULLIF` is handy when you're working with legacy data that contains a mixture of null values and empty strings.

Example:
`SELECT(COALESCE(NULLIF(firstColumn, ''), secondColumn) FROM table WHERE this = that`

Answer (score 1):

`SUM` and `COUNT` have the behavior of turning nulls into zeros. I could see `NULLIF` being handy when you want to undo that behavior. If fact this came up in a [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190723/sql-server-2005-how-to-compare-field-value-and-return-a-count-if-different-fo/6190769#6190769) I provided. If I had remembered NULLIF I probably would have written the following

```
SELECT student, 
       NULLIF(coursecount,0) as courseCount 
FROM   (SELECT cs.student, 
               COUNT(os.course) coursecount 
        FROM   @CURRENTSCHOOL cs 
               LEFT JOIN @OTHERSCHOOLS os 
                 ON cs.student = os.student 
                    AND cs.school <> os.school 
        GROUP  BY cs.student) t
```